# Как отслеживать много движущихся объектов?

Tags: python, opencv

В документации есть примеры, как можно отслеживать один объект, предварительно выделив его bounding box. Или как отслеживать объект определённого цвета. Но как отслеживать все объекты, которые двигаются в видео? Причём множество движущихся объектов может меняться: одни останавливаются, другие начинают двигаться. Цвет объектов тоже может меняться.

Хотелось бы увидеть пример или узнать готовый метод, если такой есть.

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть [здесь](https://gist.github.com/harshilpatel312/ff08b49fd71a3eeaeb209c91de3dfde1)

Answer (score 2):

Для этой задачи используются оптические потоки, которые также реализованы в OpenCV. Пример кода из [документации](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/dee/tutorial_optical_flow.html):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
cap = cv.VideoCapture(cv.samples.findFile("vtest.avi"))
ret, frame1 = cap.read()
prvs = cv.cvtColor(frame1,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
hsv = np.zeros_like(frame1)
hsv[...,1] = 255

while True:
    ret, frame2 = cap.read()
    next = cv.cvtColor(frame2,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    flow = cv.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prvs,next, None, 0.5, 3, 15, 3, 5, 1.2, 0)
    mag, ang = cv.cartToPolar(flow[...,0], flow[...,1])
    hsv[...,0] = ang*180/np.pi/2
    hsv[...,2] = cv.normalize(mag,None,0,255,cv.NORM_MINMAX)
    bgr = cv.cvtColor(hsv,cv.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
    cv.imshow('frame2',bgr)
    
    k = cv.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break
    elif k == ord('s'):
        cv.imwrite('opticalfb.png',frame2)
        cv.imwrite('opticalhsv.png',bgr)
    
    prvs = next
```